# Why does Plink not behave the same as PuTTY with serial connection?

Tags: serial-port, putty, plink

I am trying to programmatically communicate with a device connected over a serial connection.  When I send commands using PuTTY, I have no problems.  But when I try to communicate using Plink, I get no response.  What would cause that difference?

I connect to PuTTY through the command line using `putty -serial com3 -sercfg 9600` and then send my commands from within the PuTTY window using Ctrl-J (to adjust for the line endings, I think? It works in any case).

And I connect to plink using `plink -serial com3 -sercfg 9600`, but then neither enter nor Ctrl-J or any combination seem to send my commands.

Comment: What exact configuration are you using in Putty? ie how many bits, stop bits, start bits, handshake?

Comment: If you're just using default everything, try doing `plink -serial COM3 -sercfg 9600,8,1,n,X`

Comment: What happens, if you create a text file with the command followed by LF character (ASCII code 10 = `Ctrl+J`) and redirect PLink input from the file?